# java.lang.ArithmeticException: Division is undefined

Tags: java

I have a simple operation going on in my program:

```
exposureNoDecimals =
    BigDecimal.valueOf(curEffSpreadPremium).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)).divide(wsRate, 0,
        java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).longValue();
```

exposureNoDecimals - long
curEffSpreadPremium - long
wsRate - BigDecimal

However I am getting

```
"java.lang.ArithmeticException: Division is undefined" 
  at java.math.BigDecimal.longScaledDivide(BigDecimal.java:3105)
  at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:2409)
  at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:2396)
  at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:2361)
```

The problem is the issue is recreatable on production and not on my machine (cant debug, or cant see the inputs)

What can be the issue here? Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: That's why you need logs.

Comment: Try to log the error message in a log file with log4j. Then you can see where and why this error occurs

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take a look at the source code for `BigDecimal` (e.g. [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigDecimal.java/)).

An `ArithmeticException` is only thrown with the message "Division undefined" when you attempt to divide zero by zero.

I'm not going to suggest a fix, because the >>correct<< fix will depend on what this calculation is supposed to be doing, and why the divisor / dividend happen to be zero.  Putting in some zero checks might be a solution, but it could also be a "band-aid solution" that hides the problem rather than fixing it.  It could come back to bite you later on.

---

> The problem is the issue is recreatable on production and not on my machine (cant debug, or cant see the inputs)

As noted in various comments, there are different versions of `BigDecimal` depending on the Java version and (apparently) vendor.  One of the differences between (some) versions is that the exception messages differ.

If you really want to track this down this reproducibility issue, you are going to have to look at the source code for `BigDecimal` in production and on your machine.  (Unfortunately, a stacktrace involving Java SE classes is often difficult to diagnose without precise Java vendor and version number information.  It is not helpful in this case ... for that reason.)

Comment: Agreed. The "Division undefined"  is thrown only on 0/0 types, but when I am using a dummy program for attempting 0/0, it gives me "/ by 0 exception" rather than division is undefined.

Comment: Worth mentioning the extended trace:  at java.math.BigDecimal.longScaledDivide(BigDecimal.java:3105) at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:2409) at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:2396) at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:2361)

Comment: That does not match the current Oracle source code.  There is no `longScaledDivide` method.  You must be using a different class library.  (Maybe Android?  Or a really ancient version of Sun Java?  Or an IBM version!)

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code of `BigDecimal`, `java.lang.ArithmeticException: Division undefined` (without the *is*) is only thrown when you divide zero by zero.

Looks like in your case `curEffSpreadPremium` *and* `wsRate` both are zero.

So you need to guard the line with zero-checks.

Comment: Agreed. The "Division undefined" is thrown only on 0/0 types, but when I am using a dummy program for attempting 0/0, it gives me "/ by 0 exception" rather than division is undefined.

Comment: `BigDecimal` supports two different messages. One for `x/0` and one for `0/0`.

Comment: According to the Bigdecimal Code:
{
public BigDecimal More ...divide(BigDecimal divisor) {
1581        /*
1582         * Handle zero cases first.
1583         */
1584        if (divisor.signum() == 0) {   // x/0
1585            if (this.signum() == 0)    // 0/0
1586                throw new ArithmeticException("Division undefined");  // NaN
1587            throw new ArithmeticException("Division by zero");
1588        }
1589
}

So when i do 0/0. it should throw Division Undefined, but instead i am getting division by 0.

Comment: Yes it should. Perhaps that justifies a new question to Stackoverflow (please note that JDK line numbers aren't very helpful, without the exact JDK version number).
But looking at it pragmatically, to solve your issue, you need to add zero-checks.

Comment: Looks like i have figured out why I was getting the division is undefined on the server(running websphere) and / by 0 on my machine(running tomcat). Got hold of the data that was causing the issue and indeed 0/0 was present and the same data was causing / by zero exception on my machine and division undefined. Looks like the case that websphere throws custom messages for exceptions or rather changes the same? (Another proof being i getting "division is undefined" rather than "division undefined": as written in the bigdecimal code)

Comment: Years ago, IBM used its own JDK. Perhaps it still does and we are seeing proof of it right here.